# Verify proof that $e^n \in O(4^n)$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, asymptotics

I'm looking for someone to verify my proof to this, as I'm unsure whether I have actually proven it.

Prove that $e^n \in O(4^n)$

Therefore, I have to show that there exists a $c$ such that $\frac{e^n}{4^n} \leq c $ $\forall n \geq n_0 $.

Choosing $n_0 = 1$, i get $c = \frac{e}{4}$.

Induction, base case $(n=1)$:

$\frac{e}{4} \leq c = \frac{e}{4} $

Proving that if it applies to $n$, then it also applies to $n+1$:

$\frac{e^n}{4^n} \leq \frac{e}{4} \dots \frac{e^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}}\leq1$

$\frac{e^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}} \leq \frac{e}{4} \dots \frac{e^{n}}{4^{n}}\leq1$

Does this actually pass as a proof? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use that $e < 3 < 4$ and hence $e/4 < 1$ so that $e^n/4^n = (e/4)^n \to 0$?

Comment: Yup, I know that the fact the limit as n tends to infinity is 0 can be used to prove the statement for both big O and small o. I was however wondering if the approach above can be used as well.